# AJAX request takes too long to complete the request

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, codeigniter-2

I have a MySQL query which gets 17000 rows. If i execute that query directly in MySQL terminal using Putty, it takes 17 ~ 20 sec to get all rows. This is fine.

But when i tried to execute the query using PHP with an AJAX request, It takes 50 ~ 60 sec to complete the request, even this query was cached.

I am using CodeIgniter PHP framework for caching and its AJAX request.

I agree, the HTTP request and PHP execution might take time when compared to direct MySQL query execution in the terminal.

MySQL direct query execution : 20 sec
Using HTTP, php, Codeigniter and JSON format and it is cached : 60 sec.

The time difference too long i guess.

Model query that i am trying to execute:

```
mysql> explain SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, IFNULL(col5,'N/A') AS 'col55', `col6`, col7, col8, col9 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.fkid_colid=`voyage id` AND table1.alias_type='voyage_display' WHERE column10='voyage';
+----+-------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys                       | key     | key_len | ref                                | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1       | ALL  | NULL                                | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                               | 37770 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1       | ref  | PRIMARY,fk_table1_colid_idx         | PRIMARY | 4       | database.table1.column ID |     1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Have any idea for this longer loading time? it would be if you suggest any optimization techniques for this?

Comment: `17 ~ 20` sec is again a bit higher what is the query you are using ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is a mysql join query.

Comment: Yes please add that query into the question. And perhaps the following would give better idea `explain select...` this will give you the explain plan add result from that in the question.

Comment: Due to security reason, i can't add the real query. As you suggest, i have added a sample query for your information, so you can get some idea.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you add any indexes to the tables you are using (specifically column10, which has the "where" on it) which would improve the performance overall?  Do you really need to be returning 17k rows at a time?

Comment: Really thank you for suggestions. My problem is not about the query, but the ajax request really taking too long time to load, even though the mysql query being cached by codeigniter. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I just found the issue by profiling the controller function.

So as per the Codeigniter profiling the result as below,

Controller Execution Time : 27.7074 seconds.

And after that i looked Chrome console for the time taken to complete the request, From that i came to know one issue.

```
Stalled : 17.32 s
DNS Lookup: 1.000 ms
Initial connection  :262.000 ms
Request/Response        TIME
Request sent    0
Waiting (TTFB)  1.03 s
Content Download    29.84 s
Total time: 48.46 s
```

From the report, the big issue is "Stalled" time. It took 17.32 seconds. It was happened due to my side proxy issue and It cannot be avoid and it won't happen in my customer side. So it is negligible.

So,

Direct query execution 17 ~ 20 seconds

Ajax request for content download in browser side: 29 ~ 30 seconds.

So the difference is 10 seconds for 3MB content download and my customer is accepted :)

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: I have the same issue... I don't get it why the "Content Download" takes sooo long... while everything else runs fast.

Answer (score 0):

Your query

```
SELECT 
col1, 
col2, 
col3, 
col4, 
IFNULL(col5,'N/A') AS 'col55', 
`col6`, 
col7, 
col8, 
col9 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.fkid_colid=`voyage id` AND table1.alias_type='voyage_display' 
WHERE column10='voyage';
```

From the explain plan its pretty clear that the usage of `where` is not using index and instead trying to scan the entire table.

You will need an index to be added as

```
alter table table1 add index column10_idx(column10);
```

The above column is used in the `where clause`, the joining clause looks good and are resolving the index.

Make sure to take a backup of the DB before applying the index. After applying the index check the query speed.